# Applying --citeproc without converting file format, only working between certain formats

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

for some reason I can't find the answer to this question anywhere! I have a `.docx` file with Pandoc-friendly citation keys (`[@nameTitle2024]`), exported from Ulysses. I want to apply citations to the Word file, outputting a word file.

If I export my writing to Markdown and run
`pandoc mock.md --bibliography=lib.bib --citeproc --csl=chicago-author-date.csl --output=output.docx`, everything works just fine. But if I try to go between the same format (md to md or docx to docx), the citations aren't applied. None of the following commands work:

`pandoc mock.rtf --bibliography lib.bib --citeproc --csl chicago-author-date.csl -o Mock3.docx --reference-doc=Mock2.docx`

`pandoc mock.docx --bibliography=lib.bib --citeproc --csl=chicago-author-date.csl --output=output.md`

Comment: For Markdown, try `--to=markdown-citations`. For docx, Markdown syntax won't work. Use Zotero and `--from=docx+citations` to use citations in office-files.